# How to locate buffer overruns in a .NET program that calls native functions

Tags: c#, .net, buffer-overflow

I have a C# program that makes several calls to a native image processing library (MIL).  The library is not type safe; we need to be very careful when calling a function, making sure we provide the proper buffer type / size.

Is there a way in Visual Studio, or is there a tool, to detect when a buffer overrun occurs?  In C/C++ applications, MSVC adds a special zone after buffers (in debug) to detect overruns.  That would be useful in .Net applications that call native code.

Comment: Just the debugger, it automatically breaks when the condition is detected.  Project > Properties > Debug tab, "Enable native code debugging" checkbox ticked.  Having to build the native code from source so you have a good PDB file tends to be the hangup.

Comment: Hi Hans, unfortunately it didn't work.  There was nothing in the output after the program exited.  Maybe that was a timing issue, but I tested with another program, forcing a buffer overflow, and nothing is logged in the program output and no exception occurs.